# Making your Windows 7 a WIFI hotspot for Android?

Tags: windows-7, android, wireless-networking

I use a broadband dongle on my Windows 7. I want to expose my laptop as a wifi hotspot so that i can use internet on my samsung galaxy ace.

I have tried Connectify but my chipset is not supported so it simply make the adhoc network. Tried Bzeek. My phone get connected, but no browsing.

Any solution that you guys have?

PS: I am in no mood to root my device.

Comment: Bummer to hear Connectify didn't work for you.

Comment: As I previously said on your previous question, try this method: [http://superuser.com/a/1070755/588105](http://superuser.com/a/1070755/588105)

Answer (score 3):

You could try VirtualRouter, which seems to fit the bill:
http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my question. It also does not work. It does not detect wireless connection to populate in its combo.

Comment: Could it be a driver issue? Are there any other alternative driver versions you could try that may enable this functionality? - it may be blocked somehow by design.

Comment: @Tahir Akram - I installed VirtualRouter and the wireless connection desn't show up in the combo only the ethernet connection. - Works for me (in hotel)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the built-in feature of Windows 7 for hosting a WiFi network using infrastructure mode?

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<SSID> key=<Password>
```

Don't forget to start it after creating it by using:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

If you desire to stop or see how it's currently configured, use:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

If your smartphone still can't connect to the Internet, you might need to enable the Internet Connection Sharing option that you can find on your network adapter properties under the Sharing tab:

[image: Screenshot of the option]

Answer (score 0):

Software Name is **"Connectify"**, Create Hotspot and it can access using Android Device..

Comment: The OP already stated in the question it doesn't work for him.