# Making your PC a WIFI hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking

I use a broadband dongle on my Windows 7. I want to expose my laptop as a wifi hotspot so that i can use internet on my samsung galaxy ace.

I have tried Connectify but my chipset is not supported so it simply make the adhoc network. Tried Bzeek. My phone get connected, but no browsing.

Any solution that you guys have? Please let me know. And lets solve this puzzle.

Thanks.

PS: I am in no mood to root my device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works without rooting your device. I had to do the same for my phone. From whatever I read on the net, Android by default does not support adhoc networks, at least till Android v2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html). This will not make your PC a Wi-Fi HotSpot but it will allow you to connect your mobile to internet which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the built-in feature of Windows 7 for hosting a WiFi network as infrastructure mode?

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<SSID> key=<Password>
```

And don't forget to start it after creating it by using:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

And if you desire to stop or see how it's currently configured use:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

If your smartphone still wont be able to connect to internet, it might be needed to enable the internet connection sharing by the options that you will find on your network adapter properties (tab Sharing)
[Screenshot of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmSgc.png)

Comment: If you find a question which is identical to an existing question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of reposting your answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new to Superuser, I didn't know that I could have flag as duplicated even if I had no reputation at that time, sorry ;)

Comment: it's fine, just wanted to let you know for the future. Thanks for your contributions!