# Wifi Hotspot on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, android

I have a wifi router with MAC-address filter. My laptop is allowed but my android phone isn't. I want to share my laptop's wifi connection with my phone. I have tried several wifi tethering programs, but they make just access point to my router and it still doesn't allow my phone to access Internet. I would like to solve this whitout change the router's allowed-MAC-addresses list. I have ESET Smart Security 7 installed on my laptop, so can it be any problem? How can I make it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/306090/making-your-windows-7-a-wifi-hotspot-for-android?rq=1 while the question was about "Windows 7" the propose solution supports Windows 8.

Comment: Try Connectify-me as already pointed out by the post mentioned in the previous comment! You can also try Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) in the properties of your network connection of laptop. Connectify-me is easier than the latter.